# Creating p12 iOS developer certificate on Windows - error in last step

Tags: ios, openssl, certificate

So, I've been looking around a lot of how to create a p12 file for iPhone development, and I think I'm doing exactly as I am supposed to, but at the last step I get some errors that are more or less impossible to decipher.

I am running Windows 7, and these are the steps I do:

1) Create the private key. I do this by running this command (cmd is opened in Administrator mode):

> openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2048

2) Create the CSR file

> openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out developer_identify.csr

3) Upload the csr file to the iPhone dev site. Here I do the following:

- Click on menu Identifiers --> App IDs, select the correct App ID, click Edit, click Create Certificate, click Continue, select the CSR-file created above and proceed. Wait for the site to tell me its all OK, and then download the *aps_development.cer* file.

4) Create the PEM file:

> openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform DER -out
>   developer_identity.pem -outform PEM

5) And lastly, create the p12 file (**and this is where it fails**):

> openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem
>   -out iphone_dev.p12

The output after the last command:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
8216:error:060740A0:lib(6):func(116):reason(160):NA:0:
8216:error:23077073:lib(35):func(119):reason(115):NA:0:
8216:error:2306C067:lib(35):func(108):reason(103):NA:0:
8216:error:23073067:lib(35):func(115):reason(103):NA:0:
```

The p12 file is 0 bytes.

The PEM file looks alright, starts with

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
then a lot of jibberish and then ends with
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```